# Catching service property changes in Angular components

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Could you help with my problem? Sorry in advance for my English. So I'm trying to teach Angular and write some simple app. But I have a problem with passing props from service to component.

Situation: I have a service which send request to API by ***getWeather()*** and set the answer in a prop ***weatherCatalog***. But for right build URL he need get user coords by methods ***setUrl()*** and ***setPosition()***

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WeatherService {
    key = 'dd6301427900459c863160646190201';
    weatherCatalog;
    queryString = '';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  setUrl(position) {
    this.queryString = `http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx?key=${this.key}&q=${position.coords.latitude},${position.coords.longitude}&num_of_days=14&tp=4&format=json`;

    this.getWeather()
  }

  getWeather() {
    this.http.get(this.queryString)
        .subscribe(
            res => this.weatherCatalog = res,
            err => console.error(err)
        );
  }

  setPosition() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.setUrl.bind(this))
  }
}
```

Also, I have a component where I trying copy passed by service request Object in component property ***weather***. But there is my problem, of course, it doesn't work. I think because in the moment of set property in component property in service have an undefined value. I tried to use Observable and other rxjs things in many ways, but no result (my hands from the azz guilty in this I suppose).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-current-weather',
  templateUrl: './current-weather.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./current-weather.component.scss']
})
export class CurrentWeatherComponent implements OnInit {
  weather;

  constructor(private weatherService: WeatherService) {
    this.weather = weatherService.weatherCatalog
  }

  ngOnInit() {
        this.weatherService.setPosition();
  }

}
```

My idea was - I get user coords, and after this send a request to API. Gotten answer and save it in service property, after this passing it to the component where copy it in a component property. And if the value of property in service will be changed - the value of property in a component should get this change.

It looks easy but I really stuck. Will be so appreciate if you could suggest how I cant realize it or where I can read about tools which help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

import { WeatherService } from './weather.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  weather$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private weatherService: WeatherService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  async getWeather() {
    try {
      const position  = await this.weatherService.getCurrentPosition();
      this.weather$ = this.weatherService.getWeather(position);
    } catch(error) {
      this.weather$ = of(`You'll not get the Geolocation Services to work in this mode. Try Clicking on the 'Open in New Window LIVE' button to see if that works for you!`);
    }
  }
}
```

In the Component Template:

```
<button (click)="getWeather()">Get Weather</button>
<pre>
  {{ weather$ | async | json }}
</pre>
```

And in the Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class WeatherService {
  key = 'dd6301427900459c863160646190201';
  weatherCatalog;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getWeather(position) {
    const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
    const queryString = `https://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx?key=${this.key}&q=${latitude},${longitude}&num_of_days=14&tp=4&format=json`;
    return this.http.get(queryString);
  }

  async getCurrentPosition() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        res => resolve(res),
        err => reject(err)
      );
    });
  }

}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Demo**](https://get-weather-based-on-users-current-location.stackblitz.io) of this implementation.

---

> Here's the [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-weather-based-on-users-current-location?file=src%2Fapp%2Fweather.service.ts) for the code.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's helped me a lot.